# c# check for exact type

Tags: c#, types

I want to check the type of an object. I only want to return true if the type is exact the same. Inherited classes should return false.

eg:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

B b = new B();

// The next line will return true, 
// but I am looking for an expression that returns false here
if(b is A)
```

Comment: Your example and your question don't make sense together.  You say you only want to return true if the type is inherited, but then show that an inherited comparison should return false.

Comment: I think you mean you only want to return true when it's the exact same type (not inherited). Otherwise the comment in your code is wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(b is A)` checks b for type compatibility with A which means it checks both the inheritance hierarchy of b and the implemented interfaces for Type A.

`b.GetType() == typeof(A)` on the other hand checks for the **exact** same Type. If you don't qualify the Types further (i.e. casting) then you're checking the declared type of b.

In either case (using either of the above), you will get `true` if b is the exact type of A.

Be careful to know why you want to use exact types in one situation over another:

- For example, to check exact types defeats the purpose of OO Polymorphism which you might not wish to ultimately do.
- However, for example, if you're implementing a specialized software design pattern like Inversion of Control IoC container then you will sometimes want to work with exact types.

**Edit:**

In your example,

```
if(b is A) // this should return false
```

turn it into an exact declared Type check using:

```
if (b.GetType() == typeof(A))
```

Answer (score 55):

```
b.GetType() == typeof(A)
```

Comment: In original example, he'd want: `b.GetType() == typeof(A)` because 'a' isn't declared.

Comment: That's why I posted my answer, one minuted after this.

Answer (score 9):

use:

```
if (b.GetType() == typeof(A)) // this returns false
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code sample seems to be the opposite of your question.

```
bool isExactTypeOrInherited = b is A;
bool isExactType = b.GetType() == a.GetType();
```

Comment: You mean typeof(a) in the second line, not a.GetType(), yes?

Comment: I meant a big A in the first line of course :-> ... f1x0red

Answer (score 3):

```
bool IsSameType(object o, Type t) {
  return o.GetType() == t;
}
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
IsSameType(b, typeof(A));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It is perfectly legal -- rare, but legal -- for two different types to have the same full name but be different types. Why not just compare o.GetType() to t, rather than going through the names?  (If you are in the unfortunate situation of having two types with the same full name and you need to use them in the same assembly then you can use an imported assembly alias to tell them apart.)